# circle node on an ellipse

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, decorations

I want to put this node on an ellipse at about the 35% mark

```
\node[draw, circle, inner sep = .08cm, scale = .75] (location) {2};

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.markings, decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[decoration = {markings, mark = at position 0.3 with {\arrow{>}},} ]
  \clip (-5,0) rectangle (1,2.5);
  \draw[postaction = decorate] (-2,0) ellipse (3cm and 2cm);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: @PeterGrill I mean path length

Comment: @PeterGrill there isn't a way to do this in tikz without doing the math?  Like I have done with the arrow placement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `markings` library that you used for placing the arrow to also place the node:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.markings, decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[
    decoration = {
        markings,
        mark = at position 0.3 with {\arrow{>}},
        mark = at position 0.3 with {\node[draw, circle, inner sep = .08cm, scale = .75] (location) {2};}
    } ]
  \clip (-5,0) rectangle (1,2.5);
  \draw[postaction = decorate] (-2,0) ellipse (3cm and 2cm);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe also mentioning to use an ellipse shaped node referral with an angle anchor would be useful. Oh wait I just did :P